# Requiring user login with omniauth on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm having some difficulty requiring user login through omniauth (with twitter). I have a session_controller, user model and authorizations model setup.

It seems like the problem is that I can't access the omniauth hash. Is there any reason why?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :check_sign_in

  def check_sign_in
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 
    authentication = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    unless authentication
        redirect_to signin_path
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Could you provide the error message and the Authorization model? Where is it blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, maybe watching [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) will get you there. I followed it, and went the Twitter route, like you. It's working for me, so you should have success too.

In my application controller, I have

```
private
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

And, in my sessions model,

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You are logged  in."
  end
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'You are logged out.'
  end
end
```

and in my user's model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
end

def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    user.nickname = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
  end
end
```

Comment: What does the `create! do` loop do? Is it simply performing the `create` action from the Users controller on this information that is gathered in the for loop?

Comment: yes, using the User as the model, it takes the auth details from omniauth and populates the User model's properties, creating them at then end. In general, methods that end in `!`, like `create!`, indicate that the method will modify the object it's called on.